# Remove core-js from nextjs bundle

Tags: javascript, next.js, babeljs

I am trying to reduce nextjs project's bundle sizes. There is a `core-js` bundle for polyfills. I want to remove this core-js from the main bundle size. It has 50KB of size.

I tried to use custom babel configuration like this:

```
    {
        "presets": [
            [
                "next/babel",
                {
                    "useBuiltIns": "usage",
                    "corejs": "3"
                }
            ]
        

]
}
```

But it didn't help.

How can I remove the corejs from a NextJS project?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: By default, Next.js does not includes `core-js` https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/8a76a8f0499faba1f96b69317edf49c5dd1e31bb/packages/next/build/babel/preset.ts#L172
See more: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/supported-browsers-features#polyfills

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "next/babel"
    ]
  ]
}
```

source: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/6931#issuecomment-633247029

Alternatively:

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "next/babel",
      {
        "preset-env": {
          "useBuiltIns": "entry",
          "corejs": "3"
        }
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

source: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/6931#issuecomment-633158748